# Rails 3 loading message list in an accordion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, accordion

I have a standard accordion that looks like

```
<h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
        ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
        amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
        odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
        purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
        velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
        suscipit faucibus urna.
        </p>
    </div>
```

and currently my view loads a list of messages like

```
    <ul id="msgs_list">
        <% msgs.each do |msg| %>
            <div class="msg_message_container">
                <%= h msg.title %>
                <%= h msg.message %><br />
        <% end %>
    </ul>
```

How can I wrap the title of each message in the h3 accordion tags and have each message in a separate accordion div? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this code work for you? I got rid of the `ul` and the div for `msg_message_container` however adding them back if you need them should be easy.

```
<% msgs.each do |msg| %>
  <h3><a href="#"><%= h msg.title %></a></h3>
    <div>
      <p>
        <%= h msg.message %>
      </p>
    </div>
<% end %>
```